# After uploading codeigniter in cpanel it cannot find models

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I am working with codeigniter 3.0 in xampp localhost and it is working perfectly. But when I am uploading the files in my server via cPanel it is giving me this error

> 'Unable to locate the model you have specified: User_model'

I have also tried uploading a new codeigniter project but gave the same result.

I did some search and found that it can be a permission issue but in my cpanel project folder, all folders permissions are set to 0755 and files permissions are set to 0644 but still not working.

Please help me.

Edit: Problem is fixed. As in codeigniter 3 the model file names (such as User_model.php) must be starts with uppercase letters.

Comment: are you sure your file name is lowercase just as: user_model.php and the class is typed `class User_model extends CI_Model`?

Comment: Problem is fixed. In codeignitor 3 model file names (like User_model.php) must be starts with uppercase letters.

Comment: Please post the resolution as an answer (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)